# OrmLite with nested select queries

Tags: c#, crud, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have generalised my problem in order to cater to the largest number of people with similar issues.

```
public class Table1 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    public string FieldC { get; set; }
}

public Table2 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public Table1 FieldA { get; set; }
    public DateTime FieldB { get; set; }
    public int FieldC { get; set; }
}

public Table3 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public List<Table2> FieldA { get; set; }
    public List<Table1> FieldB { get; set; }
}

public Table4 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Table3))]
    public int Table3_id { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Table2))]
    public int Table2_id { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I populate a `List` containing the complete information of Table4?** I.e.: including the value of each field of its referenced tables—and the referenced tables of those

I would also be interested in how I could create a single CRUD form—from the JSON serialisation—which can create an entirely new Table4 entry nesting the CRUD forms for Table3, Table2 and Table1.

Thanks for all help

Comment: hi Gray, OrmLite is also a C# ORM library: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from multiple tables in 1 query you need to use an SQL JOIN that's mapped to a Merged Poco which matches the returned result-set, see the Shipper Examples in this answer for an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617860/85785

Comment: So neither nested select queries nor joins are supported by OrmLite? - I.e.: I would need to write pure SQL? - Any chance you can add support for either of these methods?

Comment: What would you like the API to look like?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I recommend: [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) sort of syntax.

Comment: And what do you expect to get back? OrmLite is a .NET 3.5 (i.e. no dynamic) that works on strong-typed POCOs, by their nature JOINs deviate from the shape of the POCOs - so there is no existing shape you can hydrate into. Hence why the current solution looks like it does.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't need a join. Nested select queries would work fine. Even if I could store a list containing Table4 and everything inside it unrolled, I would then be able to use some fancy javascript on the frontend to CRUD any entry at any layer of the schema. So how can I populate this `List`?

Comment: You have to use SQL for nested queries (or any other query requiring more than 1 table).

Comment: Well would it be possible to generalise this to a set without dynamically creating POCOs? - I.e. just a list of lists

Comment: Great, send me a pull request for it :)