# ServiceStack ORMLite - Select columns

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I recently started working with ServiceStack and its ORMLite framework. I have searched on Google and browsed the source code but couldn't find anything relevent.

Is there any way to select specific columns when executing a query with ORMLite ?
Something like that : `Db.First<Model>(q => q.Id == someId, "Column1, Column2")`

Unless I missed this feature, I am surprised nobody asked about this before, since this is one the rule of thumbs to optimize your DB transactions.

Comment: Hi cobolstinks, and thanks for your answer. I think you are talking about the Java version which is meant to run on mobile devices. I am in fact refering to the ServiceStack.ORMLite framework, which is a C# port meant to be used in ASP.Net applications

Comment: yeap my bad i was referring to ormlite and was using it with ADK.  I removed my original comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to specify columns other that the table you need to use SQL as [seen in this earlier example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617860/85785)

So in your case you could do something like:

```
Db.First<Model>("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM AnyTableOrView");
```

You can also create a partial model that looks at your table by decorating it with the `[Alias]` attribute, like:

```
[Alias("AnyTableOrView")]
public class Model {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Db.First<Model>(q => q.Id == someId);
```

And it will only SELECT + populate fields from the partial model.

Comment: I was using the first way you described, but your second approach is way cleaner. Thanks and keep up the good work.

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders, if you aliased your Id attribute, you also have to alias it in the stripped down model you use for querying.

Answer (score 2):

I did try this :

1. Created a Database VIEW (table name and columns are already set)
2. Created a class named "Event" and matching each fields for that table with a property
   (i used [Alias] for table name and for all columns to have nice names)
3. Wrote access to DB to select 1 record based on it's ID

   ```
       var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
           "Data Source=MyDB;User Id=user;Password=pwd",  // Connection String
           OracleDialect.Provider);

       using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
       {
               var event = db.GetByIdOrDefault<Event>( request.Id );
       }
   ```

At that point the var 'event' is populated but only the Id field is filled ! 
all the others fields of the class are not filled (while there are really data in database).

It's the simplest i can do and it does not work. Any ideas ? 
(PS : i am using OrmLite for Oracle)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.
It was due to an incorrect type matching between field in my class (defined as a string) and the corresponding Oracle Field (that is a DATE).

I replaced the string with datetime and worked like a charm.

So it's working perfectly with a VIEW and that's GREATLY simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, however my solution was different.

I had a int property in my POCO.  My query (from Oracle) was returning a null for this property.  It caused a exception to be raised and prevented further processing of that row.
The result was a partial populated POCO.

The solution was to change to type to be nullable.

```
public int? mypropperty
```